How to obtain the access_hash and file_reference for createStickerSet in Telegram?
in my code below:
  sticer = "0.webm"


  upload_sticker = await client.upload_file(sticker)

  my_Stickers = InputStickerSetItem(document=InputDocument(id=upload_sticker.id,access_hash=upload_sticker.access_hash,file_reference=upload_sticker.file_reference),emoji="")


  result = await client(CreateStickerSetRequest(user_id=user, title="testset", short_name="jjkakschan_by_cool_bot", stickers=[my_Stickers]))

I'm trying to get the access_hash and file_reference but I don't know what returns them
I have webm files in the right format and encoding and I want to create a video sticker set using them, here I only used 1 for demonstration.
my question is do I get the access hash and file reference of my uploaded webm files ?
the client.upload only returns:
InputFile(id=-67133921635690008, parts=1, name='0.webm', md5_checksum='5188d68feebc242395e98819582bac29')
but I believe I need InputDocument

file_reference is a temporary random bytestring used to access media (such as download). This means the media must've been sent or saved previously, and you accessed it through (most likely) a message.
If the media hasn't been set, you need to use the InputMedia constructors with Uploaded in their name. There is only two of these: InputMediaUploadedDocument and InputMediaUploadedPhoto.
Photos are only intended to be image files that will be compressed by the server.
So that leaves you with just InputMediaUploadedDocument. And that's what you must create, since it takes an InputFile as a parameter.
InputMediaUploadedDocument(file=input_file, mime_type='application/octet-stream', attributes=[])`

Adjust as needed.
To go from an uploaded document to a document, you must upload the media (not the file, which you've already uploaded) using UploadMediaRequest.
This will likely return a MessageMediaDocument, which you can use with utils.get_input_media.
This is extremely confusing, but it's how the API works.

I didn't have to use utils.get_input_media for my case, all I had to do is to use res2 = await client(UploadMediaRequest(peer=user, media=media))  with media as InputMediaUploadedDocument and I got the Document  I wanted !
